# 400 Bad Request Required: X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I've been using oath 2 for all my fusion table queries as described here: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/oauthfusiontables). From today I'm getting this response for all queries: Error 400 Bad request:Required: X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable.

Can't find similar issues with google search. No change to my code recently-was there any changes made to fusion tables API or oath 2 recently that I'm not aware of that can cause this error? Please help

Comment: unfortunately I only can confirm that issue: the SELECT statement following the syntax described [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using?hl=ja#queryData) results in that error, INSERT INTO, CREATE TABLE and IMPORT still work. I'm also waiting for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Fusion Tables product roll out included a change that enforced request safety. The side effect of this is that GET requests with alt=csv that use the access_token=[your token] argument result in an error.

The immediate fix is to use an authorization header and remove the access_token=[your token]  argument from the GET request.

The request header should include
Authorization: Bearer [your token]

We are working on a more permanent fix which would re-enable GET requests with access_token=[your token] arguments. This may take a few hours