# Fusion tables 400 error

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have made an app that collects data from my robotics competition and then sends it to a fusion table. It has worked before this and was working last time it was tested one week ago now when I try to send the data I get this

```
Transmission Error400 Bad
Request Required:X-Goog-
Encode-Respnse-If-
ExecutableBad transmission
```

this is the error as formatted that is happening in the app. the only Idea I have is that it may be a security issue because it is a 400 error but I cannot even begin to know where to start the competition is tomorrow and the copies from previously do not work either I need help quickly other info is that is was made using app inventor 2

Comment: A 400 error means it is a client-side error, so your request is not accepted. Can you post code on how you do requests?

Comment: duplicate of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663191/400-bad-request-required-x-goog-encode-response-if-executable

Comment: it seems to be, that Google fixed the problem... just try again...